# Deleting a line from a text file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to build a system for bookings and payments, i currently have multiple variables saving to a file fine. What i need to do is add a payment to the set bookingID, now i have sorted it so it adds the changed payments totals to the file but i cant get it to delete the old ones. So when it searches the file it finds the old one first where the customer has only paid £50 and not the latest one where they have paid £100. So How do i read from the file and do everything i need to do with the data from it, then delete THAT SINGLE LINE OF DATA and then i know how to add the new data in. A friend mentioned using an array but i have tried looking through that on here and it has massively confused me.

Thanks in advance

There is more code above where it finds the data and displays it then this is once they have typed the amount they want to add

```
    Dim bookings As String
    bookings = "E:\Grouse Lodge Bookings\Bookings.txt"
    bookingidtemp = txtbookingid.Text
    FileOpen(1, bookings, OpenMode.Input)
    found = False
    If temp = True Then
        If found = False Then
            Do Until found = True
                Input(1, custname)
                Input(1, address1)
                Input(1, address2)
                Input(1, cost)
                Input(1, amount)
                Input(1, startdate)
                Input(1, enddate)
                Input(1, postcode)
                Input(1, bookingid)
                Input(1, remaining)
                If bookingidtemp = bookingid Then
                    txtname.Text = custname
                    txtaddress1.Text = address1
                    txtaddress2.Text = address2
                    txtcost.Text = cost
                    txtstartdate.Text = startdate
                    txtenddate.Text = enddate
                    txtpostcode.Text = postcode
                    txttopay.Text = remaining
                    found = True
                    FileClose(1)
                Else

                End If
            Loop
        End If
        If found = False Then
            MsgBox("Booking not found, please try again")
            FileClose(1)
        Else
            If found = True Then
                 FileOpen(1, bookings, OpenMode.append)  
                custname = txtname.Text
                address1 = txtaddress1.Text
                address2 = txtaddress2.Text
                cost = txtcost.Text
                amount = txtpaid.Text
                startdate = txtstartdate.Text
                enddate = txtenddate.Text
                postcode = txtpostcode.Text
                bookingid = txtbookingid.Text
                cost = txtcost.Text
                amount = txtpaid.Text
                paying = remaining - amount
                remaining = paying
                amount = cost - remaining
                WriteLine(1, custname, address1, address2, cost, amount, startdate, enddate, postcode, bookingid, remaining)
                FileClose(1)
                MsgBox("Payment added")
```

Comment: Text files are not random access.  The only way to change one line is to write out the entire file again.  Consider a database.  Also please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: What have you tried? None of us can help you unless I have something to work with, in particular a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to explain this is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Also, do check out the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Added it to the question.Sorry for the inexperience!

Comment: So at the moment it just adds an extra line of data into the file

Comment: You can just use separate file for each customer. But please don't keep your bookings in a text file...

Comment: If you must use a text file, you can read the lines into a `List(Of String)` with `Dim bkgItems As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines("E:\Grouse Lodge Bookings\Bookings.txt").ToList`. Now you can loop through all the lines with a For/Each loop, access individual lines by index number with `bkgItems(12)`, and add or delete items with the `Add` and `Delete` methods.

Comment: If im not to use a text file can someone help me do it not using a textfile?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe......

```
Public Sub rml(ByVal path As String, ByVal ln As Integer)
    Dim tb As New TextBox
    tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path)
    Dim str As New List(Of String)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each l In tb.Lines
        str.Add(tb.Lines(i))
        i += 1
    Next
    str.RemoveAt(ln - 1)
    tb.Text = ""
    For Each h In str
        tb.Text = tb.Text & h & vbNewLine
    Next
    Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(path)
    writer.Write(tb.Text)
    writer.Close()
End Sub
```

Example: `rml("C:\Users\User1\Desktop\TextEx.txt", 5)` will remove the fifth line of the text file "TextEx"